# How to direct the output of a process to stdout and pipe to another process in bash?

Tags: bash

How to direct the output of a process to stdout and pipe to another process in bash?

I am using bash shell in mac

I have two python programs `generate.py` and `sum.py`

`generate.py` prints integers to stdout.

when run using `python3 generate.py` it generates

```
1
2
3
4
...
...
```

`sum.py` just consumes the output of `generate.py` and keeps the counter and once the `generate.py` is done `sum.py` outputs the final value.

however when I run using the following bash command

`python3 generate.py >&2 | python3 sum.py` I cannot see the output of `python3 sum.py`

but if I do this `python3 generate.py | python3 sum.py` I can see the result from `sum.py` is printed to stdout but I dont see the output from `generate.py` in stdout.

so what I am looking is to see the output of both `generate.py` and `sum.py` while piping the data between them. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
python3 generate.py | tee /dev/stderr | python3 sum.py
```

But both "/dev/stderr" and "/dev/tty" are special "device file" and we should avoid using it this way.

This is easier to illustrate with an example. If we construct a chained command with pipeline, the normal expectation is, the whole chained pipeline will behave like a single coherent command (whole pipeline takes input form stdin, and write all output to stdout, and errors goes to stderr).

If I append "|wc -l" at the end (counting number of lines), it will expect it return the number of line for both "generate.py" and "sum.py".

But it will not work this way.

```
python3 generate.py | tee /dev/stderr | python3 sum.py | wc -l
```

The wc output will only be "1", which refers to the single line from "sum.py".

About "/dev/tty", it is referring to a "controlling terminal" device file. You can refers to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/what-relations-are-between-my-current-controlling-terminal-and-dev-tty/545948#545948) for more information. But in essence this is not a "device file" which should be used to generate output

Comment: why is it hacky?

Comment: I updated my response to illustrate why it is hacky

Answer (score 5):

Use the **tee** command to split your output between the tty and a program stdin

```
echo "hello" | tee /dev/tty | pbcopy
```

In your case it would be

```
python3 generate.py | tee /dev/tty | python3 sum.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this command:

```
( command1 | tee /dev/fd/3 | command2 ) 3>&1
```

The advantage is, that the complete output is combined to stdout, and stderr as second channel is still intact. So this can be used as function or script with usual redirects outside.

Translated to your commands:

```
( python3 generate.py | tee /dev/fd/3 | python3 sum.py ) 3>&1
```